# angular material saving and restoring pageSize into localStorage

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to save and restore  pageSize into localStorage.
First, on my mind I I created a directive. It works partially :) I can save pageSize. But How to read it?

Please, mighty All, hint me !

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnDestroy, HostListener, HostBinding } from 

'@angular/core';
import { UserClientOptionsService } from 'app/user-client-options.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[itemsPerPage]'
})
export class ItemsPerPageDirective implements OnDestroy {

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private optionsService: UserClientOptionsService) {
  }

  // it doesn't work. No property pageSize exists
  //@HostBinding('pageSize')
  //pageSize: number;

  @HostListener('page', ['$event'])
  onChange(e) {
    this.optionsService.update(x => x.itemsPerPage = e.pageSize);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
  }
}
```

and Html:

```
<mat-paginator [length]="src" pageSize="10" itemsPerPage [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"></mat-paginator>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are needing help with setting the paginator value after you retrieve it from localStorage, as you did not provide the code for your `UserClientOptionsService`, so I am assuming you are able to store and retrieve the value correctly from localStorage.

Based on the above assumption, I have provided both a component and directive approach in the attached stackblitz for setting the paginator value.

---

I recommend not using a generic `ElementRef` but grab a reference of the `MatPaginator` class.

`private element: MatPaginator`

With this reference you can subscribe to the native event emitter of that class and not use `@HostListener` for this.

`element.page.subscribe()`

I am using that subscription to set the value in a local variable `CurrentPageSize` when the user changes it... just add your `this.optionsService.update(e.pageSize)` logic to the subscription.

- **Please note:** you still need to set the value into a local variable as this is how you will pass the localStorage value into the
  paginator.

  ```
  public CurrentPageSize: number = 5;

  element.page.subscribe((e) => this.SetPageSizeVariable(e.pageSize));

  constructor(
      private element: MatPaginator,
      // private optionsService: UserClientOptionsService
    ) {
      element.page.subscribe((e) => this.SetPageSizeVariable(e.pageSize));
    }

      public SetPageSizeVariable(v = null) {
          if (v)
            this.CurrentPageSize = v;
          else
            this.CurrentPageSize = this.element.pageSize;
        }
  ```

---

**To pass a value into the paginator do the following**

Export your directive as `itemsPerPage`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[itemsPerPage]',
  exportAs: 'itemsPerPage'
})
```

Then in your view, set a template ref as the export `#itemsDir="itemsPerPage"`, and pass your public variable `CurrentPageSize` into the `[pageSize]` input on the `mat-paginator`.

```
<mat-paginator itemsPerPage #itemsDir="itemsPerPage" [pageSize]="itemsDir.CurrentPageSize" [length]="100"
              [pageSize]="10"
              [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

---

**Revision**

To avoid using the input attribute in the html for the Directive solution, you will need to call the `pageSize` setter each time `this.element.pageSize = v`.

```
 private _setPageSize(v) {
    this.element.pageSize = v;
  }
```

I have removed the component solution and removed all html component code from the Directive version in the stackblitz.

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o7eeku?embed=1&file=directive/ItemsPerPageDirective.ts

Comment: May be it's a good solution. But idea was do not use any html component code-behind. Ideally I should update only html <mat-paginator> adding only derective inside.

Comment: Please see revision removing all html component code.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by @Marshal's code I tried to create a persistent pageSize myself.

I've created a new directive `mPaginationItemsPerPage`:

```
import { Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, PageEvent } from '@angular/material';

const PAGE_SIZE_KEY = 'pagination_page_size';

@Directive({
    selector: '[mPaginationItemsPerPage]'
})
export class PaginationItemsPerPageDirective implements OnInit {
    private element: MatPaginator;

    get pageSize() {
        return parseInt(localStorage.getItem(PAGE_SIZE_KEY), 10);
    }

    set pageSize(size: number) {
        localStorage.setItem(PAGE_SIZE_KEY, '' + size);
    }

    constructor(private el: MatPaginator) {
        this.element = el;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.element.pageSize = this.pageSize;

        this.element.page.subscribe((page: PageEvent) => {
            this.pageSize = page.pageSize;
        });
    }
}
```

All you have to do is, to add a directive attribute to the `mat-paginator` element:

```
<mat-paginator mPaginationItemsPerPage [length]="count" [hidePageSize]="false" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[10,25,50,100]"></mat-paginator>
```